# 'Projection and Camera View' not working

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm currently following this [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/projection.html) tutorial about OpenGL, but it only shows the background color.

Prior to this tutorial, the triangle was drawn successfully.

**GLRenderer.java**

```
public class GLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
    private final float[] MVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] viewMatrix = new float[16];

    private Triangle triangle;

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 p1, javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig p2)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f); // RGBA, gives a dark gray background color
        triangle = new Triangle();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 p1, int w, int h)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method

        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

        float ratio = (float) w / h;

        Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 p1)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // clears the screen

        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(MVPMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);
        triangle.draw(MVPMatrix);
    }

    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode)
    {
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }
}
```

**Triangle.java**

```
public class Triangle
{

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "void main(){" +
        "   gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
        "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "   gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
        "}";

    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    static float TRIANGLE_COORDS[] = {
        0.0f, 0.6f, 0.0f, // top
        -0.5f, -0.3f, 0.0f, // bottom left
        0.5f, -0.3f, 0.0f // bottom right
    };

    float color[] = {0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f}; // RGBA, default gray color

    private final int glProgram;

    private int positionHandle;
    private int colorHandle;
    private int MVPMatrixHandle;

    private final int vertexCount = TRIANGLE_COORDS.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;

    public Triangle()
    {
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(TRIANGLE_COORDS.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(TRIANGLE_COORDS);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader = GLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = GLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        glProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        GLES20.glAttachShader(glProgram, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(glProgram, fragmentShader);
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(glProgram);
    }

    public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix)
    {
        GLES20.glUseProgram(glProgram);

        positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(glProgram, "vPosition");

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        colorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(glProgram, "vColor");
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(colorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        MVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(glProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0); 
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
    }
}
```

I've created a custom `View` that will hold the `GLSurfaceView`, so that I can manage to add UI elements.

What's the problem here? I've tried to debug it by altering some parts, but all of them just show the same output.

**Edit:**

This is the custom`View` that I've created.

**GLView.java**

```
    public class GLView extends GLSurfaceView
{
    public GLView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2); // Checking for OpenGL versions (1.1, 2.0, 3.0, and 3.1) in later versions
        GLRenderer glRenderer = new GLRenderer();
        setRenderer(glRenderer);

        setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        requestRender();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what pieces of code did you change for this tutorial? Also, you have set the SurfaceView to render only when requsted while not requesting to render.

Comment: I set the GLSurfaceView to RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY, and most of the code in the tutorial were not changed, only some variable names. I only meant to create a custom View holding the GLSurfaceView so that I can still include other UI elements. The above code is the complete unaltered code.

Comment: Are you calling `requestRender()`?

Comment: Well, yeah, at the custom View I've created. But still I got the same result. Where should I put it?

Comment: You've put in the right place - it should be called from the view each time you want to render a frame. Problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I suspect the float MVPMatrix, because  that is the only paramater in the draw() function. I mean, what could be its value?

Comment: Try applying the perspective projection matrix using `Matrix.perspectiveM()` in `onSurfaceChanged` just after calling `Matrix.frustumM()`.

Comment: What's the parameters? I mean, I pass the projectionMatrix, then comes a set of numbers.

Comment: `Matrix.perspectiveM( projectionMatrix, 0, FOVY, aspect, zNear, zFar )` where `FOVY` is field of view in degrees, `aspect` is a screen ratio, `zNear` is near clipping plane, `zFar` is far clipping plane. Try something like `Matrix.perspectiveM( projectionMatrix, 0, 90.0f, ratio, -2.9f, 10.0f )`.

Comment: Sorry, but still it doesn't work. I've tried a number of different options, but still the same results. Anyways, I've edited my post — I've included the custom `View` class.

Comment: Looks like you are calling `requestRender()` only once - in the class constructor. It should be called every time you want to render a frame.

Comment: How? Do I need to create another function? I've tried creating a function (`public void update()`) but it's invalid.

Comment: Generaly speaking, you need to call it whenever anything changes on-screen. Where exactly you call it is up to you. You could add a function like the one you mentioned and call it every 1/60 of a second for example.

Comment: Is `RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY` still an option here?

Comment: Yep, system will handle drawing calls then.